# html form is not submitting

Tags: php, html, forms, api

My HTML form is not submitting. I am trying to collect data from form to an API but the form is not submitting.

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
   <div class="card">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
         <div class="panel-header">
            <h4 class="text-center">Investment Preview</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="panel-body">
            <h5 class="text-center"> Credit your account </h5>
            <?php $classObj->funding(); ?>
            <form action="google.com" method="POST">
               <p class="form-control-static text-center"> Enter amount in dollar </p>
               <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>   
                  <input  type="number" name="amount" min="300" max="4999" class="form-control"  required />
               </div>
         </div>
         <div class="panel-footer">
            <button type="submit" name="fund" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat"> Invest </button>
         </div>
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is the php code for funding method

```
function funding(){
   echo "testing";
   if(isset($_POST["fund"])) {
      $amount = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conn, trim($_POST['amount'])); 
      echo $amount;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its not submitting because you have your form action as google.com

```
<form action="google.com" method="POST">
```

This needs to be changed to the correct file path that contains the processing code.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML tags are not properly nested. The second `</div>` in the form matches the `<div>` before `<form>`, so it's ending the form as well. As a result, the submit button is not inside the form.

Move that `</div>` down, after `</form>`.

Any decent editor or IDE should have warned you about unbalanced tags. You also should have noticed that the button wasn't inside the form when you opened the browser's console and checked the DOM inspector.

```html
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-header">
        <h4 class="text-center">Investment Preview</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <h5 class="text-center"> Credit your account </h5>
        <?php $classObj->funding(); ?>
        <form action="yourscript.php" method="POST">
          <p class="form-control-static text-center"> Enter amount in dollar </p>
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
            <input type="number" name="amount" min="300" max="4999" class="form-control" required />
          </div>

          <div class="panel-footer">
            <button type="submit" name="fund" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat"> Invest </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you posting it to `google.com` instead of your script?

Comment: it was a test i have removed it and it's still not working

Comment: What does the Network tab of the browser console say is happening when you click on the submit button?

Comment: it does not show any thing it acts like it is disabled

Comment: when i click button  the networks tab acts like the form was disabled

Comment: It works in my snippet. I don't know what you're doing differently on your site.

Answer (score 0):

This is form opening and closing are wrong please set like this after form submit done:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="card">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-header">
            <h4 class="text-center">Investment Preview</h4>
        </div>
        <form action="https://www.google.com" method="POST">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <h5 class="text-center"> Credit your account </h5>
                <?php $classObj->funding(); ?>
                <p class="form-control-static text-center"> Enter amount in dollar </p>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>   
                    <input  type="number" name="amount" min="300" max="4999" class="form-control"  required />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <button type="submit" name="fund" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat"> Invest </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```